# What is stdio.write in python?

Tags: python

I looked everywhere but I didn't find anything about it.
In my school, We use stdio.write or stdio.writeln instead of print.
Is there a difference betweeen them? and I don't understand that functions' purpose. Are there anyone to explain to me very clearly?

Thank you so much for replying.

edit: i asked this question nearly 2 years ago and i wanna explain what is this to guys who students.
stdio.write means like normal print.
if you write in java, you use like this code; System.out.print
actually every program has different style.

but why there is nothing about stdio.write on internet? it is because for book which taken course books. it is from special library. nothing important. just know it. it is just print. and after the finish this course you wont use this library again. it is just for understanding the logic of coding.

Comment: What software are you using when programming?

Comment: python doesn't have `stdio.write` or `stdio.writeln` functions...

Comment: I use 2.7.9 and we use stdio.write and stdio.writeln in python??

Comment: Could you show the actual code you are using?

Comment: I'm looking for `stdio.write` and I can't find a Python library that implements it, and it's not standard Python. That's why I asked if you were using some software. Something is wonky here.

Comment: https://www.photobox.co.uk/my/photo/full?photo_id=500621058499
this is code that we do this in class. and we use https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/windows/ this site because of linstall library. e.t.c maybe that's why there is

Comment: Is that photobox link supposed to link to the frontpage?

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about [this](https://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/python/code/stdio.py.html) library (which isn't a standard library, just something someone wrote), it looks like mostly a bunch of convenience functions for reading different datatypes from stdin.

As far as the difference between `stdio.write` and `print`, `stdio.write` looks to be a shim that works in both python 2 and 3 that will encode whatever unicode or byte string you have to utf-8 before it tries to write it, potentially to prevent encoding errors for some consoles that will try to encode out to ascii and fail.

```
def write(x=''):
    """
    Write x to standard output.
    """
    if (sys.hexversion < 0x03000000):
        x = unicode(x)
        x = x.encode('utf-8')
    else:
        x = str(x)
    sys.stdout.write(x)
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: I saw that link too. Why on Earth are teachers using that library to teach Python? :(

Comment: thank you for information. and i thank you other people.
i didn't know but it is clear now. at the same time i am sorry because of learning this junk codes.

Comment: @Berk It's probably best not to call it "junk" code. Presumably your lecturer has some reason for using these helper functions. But, just be aware that `stdio.write` is not part of Python itself.